# N-Dimensional Point Class

Tags: java, point, n-dimensional

```
public final class Point {
private List<Double> instance;


public Point(List<Double> instance) {
this.instance=instance;
this.setI(instance);

}
 public void  setI(List<Double> instance) {
    this.instance = instance;

}
public List<Double> getI()  {
    return this.instance;
}
protected static  Point  getPoint(List<Double> Instance)throws SQLException {
 List<Double> instance=Instance;


  return new Point(instance);
}


protected static List getPoints()throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rs;


    List points = new ArrayList();
    List x = new ArrayList();
    int rowCount = 0;
    String query1 = "Select count(*) from website;";
    Connection conn = Connection2 .getConnection("localhost", "1433", "trafficwebsite", "KEREM", "keremgulmaths");
    ResultSet rs1 = Connection3.getTableDataForQuery(query1, conn);

    while (rs1.next()) {
          rowCount = rs1.getInt(1);  } 


if (conn != null) {
        String query = "SELECT*FROM website";

        rs = Connection3.getTableDataForQuery(query, conn);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();


       //rowCount = getRowCount(rs);
        while (rs1.next()) {
          rowCount = rs1.getInt(1);  } 



        if (rowCount > 0)
        {               points = new ArrayList(rowCount);

            for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {

                rs.next();

             x.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i));


               points.add(getPoint(x));

            }
    } System.out.println(points);

    }

    return points;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{
List<Double> data=new ArrayList();
data=Point.getPoints();

System.out.println("Data: "+data);

}}


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getColumn(SQLServerResultSet.java:695)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSetMetaData.getColumnName(SQLServerResultSetMetaData.java:103)
at n.dimensional.point.Point.getPoints(Point.java:79)
at n.dimensional.point.Point.main(Point.java:95)
```

Java Result: 1

How is this problems  solved ?

How is data assigned to Point where got from the database?

Comment: What the issue do you have?waht do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

It would suffice do the `getPoints` as follows:

```
protected static List<Double> getPoints() throws SQLException {
    List<Double> points = new ArrayList<>();
    if (conn != null) {
        String query = "SELECT point FROM website"; // point ?

        try (PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                points.add(rs.getDouble(1));
            }
        }
    }
    return points;
}
```

This simplifies the querying. `rsmd.getColumnName(i)` was passed not a 1-based colum number but a 0-based row index.

The [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) `try (DECLARATIONS) {  ... }` ensures that the declared variables are always closed.

`SELECT *` is a waste and in general requires the database column definitions in a specific order.

A tip:

```
public List<Double> getI()  {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(instance);
}
```

then the original Point object cannot be changed by modifying the returned list.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    List<Double> data = Point.getPoints();
    Point pt = new Point(data);
    System.out.println("Data: "+data);
}
```

Comment: Joop, you are an experienced user with high reputation.  You don't agree that badly formulated questions should *not* be answered, since answering them encourages the OPs to keep on posting badly formulated questions?

Comment: Point is the current class. 
How to get all of data in  "website" table?

Comment: @MikeNakis (1) a beginner might be quite unorganized (2) non-native English speakers also have a handicap (3) at this stage effort is shown; in fact this code is of sufficiently nice quality. See the stack trace (in the code block, needing scrolling). Here I think programming skills (how do I write) are responsible for the chaotic impression. On the other hand, you have a point.

Comment: @keremgul maybe ask a new question with more explanation, less irrelevant code. How do you store a point in the table (table definition), What you want exactly, for what. In my answer: `Point pt = new Point(Point.getPoints());` should do. Maybe you have a problem with the database part? No structure is shown.

Comment: I do not want as stated in the link.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html

 I want to create table's(website )sizes dimensional Point  instead of 2 dimensional Point. i firmly believe that this this situation is solved with ArrayList.

Comment: @keremgul Yes, `ArrayList<Double>` could be my choice too. (For heavy calculations `double[]` would do too.)  What is still the problem?

Comment: The problem is countinued. Do you understand what i want ?

Comment: I have added the `main`   method. Maybe you should split the problem in steps, read from the database and so on.

Comment: İ do not think as you said. Because when i did as this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html i do not encountered problem.

Comment: Okay, no luck then. Bye. Good luck with your endeavour.